# Predicting document class for a single document in keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have a CNN model which was developed using keras. I have saved the model in my hard disk and for prediction purpose i reload it into memory.

```
##helper libraries
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from subprocess import check_output
from collections import Counter
import gc
from keras.models import model_from_json
import h5py

#keras library
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import time
from keras import metrics
print('import done')

# load json and create model
json_file = open('C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

I have a test data set on which i do prediction to calculate accuracy. This is done after preprocessing as follows

```
#fetch data
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\model\\data.csv')
texts = data.texts.tolist()
# labels
le = LabelEncoder()
tags = le.fit_transform(data.tags.tolist())

#preprocess
num_max = 1000
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=num_max)
tok.fit_on_texts(texts)
mat_texts = tok.texts_to_matrix(texts,mode='count')
print(tags[:5])
print(mat_texts[:5])
print(tags.shape,mat_texts.shape)

[1 1 0 1 1]
[[0. 2. 2. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 9. 3. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 2. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 4. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
(400000,) (400000, 1000)
```

Some more preprocessing code

```
# for cnn preproces
max_len = 100
cnn_texts_seq = tok.texts_to_sequences(texts)
print(cnn_texts_seq[0])
cnn_texts_mat = sequence.pad_sequences(cnn_texts_seq,maxlen=max_len)
print(cnn_texts_mat[0])
print(cnn_texts_mat.shape)

[23, 16, 31, 94, 21, 45, 26, 7, 1, 31, 7, 79, 3, 22, 5, 8, 94, 11, 137, 2, 3, 127, 81, 6, 52, 110, 10, 4, 33, 6, 210, 44, 233, 91, 4, 128, 38, 34, 10, 1, 8, 94, 38, 154, 25, 2, 651, 38, 26, 7, 8, 9, 4, 94, 10, 21, 20, 180, 97, 124, 129, 6, 224, 9, 38, 871, 44, 3, 239, 8, 53, 619, 425, 581, 467, 134, 512, 26, 163, 72, 13, 12, 925]
[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  23
  16  31  94  21  45  26   7   1  31   7  79   3  22   5   8  94  11 137
   2   3 127  81   6  52 110  10   4  33   6 210  44 233  91   4 128  38
  34  10   1   8  94  38 154  25   2 651  38  26   7   8   9   4  94  10
  21  20 180  97 124 129   6 224   9  38 871  44   3 239   8  53 619 425
 581 467 134 512  26 163  72  13  12 925]
(400000, 100)
```

When i finally predict using processed features below

```
predicted_values = np.round(loaded_model.predict(cnn_texts_mat))
```

And if i print the first 10 predicted values, i get as follows

```
print(predicted_values[0:10])
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
```

This is so far so good. However, the challenge is when i try to predict for a single document.

Below is synopsis of first 8 documents

```
0         Great CD: My lovely Pat has one of ...
1         One of the best game music soundtra...
2         Batteries died within a year ...: I bought th...
3         works fine, but Maha Energy is bett...
4         Great for the non-audiophile: Revie...
5         DVD Player crapped out after one year: I also...
6         Incorrect Disc: I love the style of this, but...
7         DVD menu select problems: I cannot scroll thr...
```

I want to predict only for the first document which is

```
single_text = '''Great CD: My lovely Pat has one of the GREAT voices of her generation. I have listened to this CD for YEARS and I still LOVE IT. When I\'m in a good mood it makes me feel better. A bad mood just evaporates like sugar in the rain. This CD just oozes LIFE. Vocals are jusat STUUNNING and lyrics just kill. One of life\'s hidden gems. This is a desert isle CD in my book. Why she never made it big is just beyond me. Everytime I play this, no matter black, white, young, old, male, female EVERYBODY says one thing "Who was that singing ?"'''
```

When i pass the single document, i get an array of different size

```
num_max = 1000
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=num_max)
tok.fit_on_texts(single_text)
mat_texts = tok.texts_to_matrix(single_text,mode='count')
print(tags[0])
print(mat_texts)
print(tags[0].shape,mat_texts.shape)

1
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
() (533, 1000)
```

#### Issue 1) Last value should be (1,1000) instead of (533,1000). Not sure why this is so

doing preprocessing further,

```
# for cnn preproces
max_len = 100
cnn_texts_seq = tok.texts_to_sequences(single_text)
print(cnn_texts_seq[0])
cnn_texts_mat = sequence.pad_sequences(cnn_texts_seq,maxlen=max_len)
print(cnn_texts_mat[0])
print(cnn_texts_mat.shape)
```

i get

```
[14]
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0 14]
(533, 100)
```

#### 2) array is again of different size. Instead of being (1,100) it is (533,100)

#### 3) Upon predicting, as expected i get array of size (533, 1) instead of only one value. Not sure why

```
predicted_values = loaded_model.predict(cnn_texts_mat)
print(predicted_values.shape)
(533, 1)
```

#### Regardless of everything i wrote above, how do i simply get predicted values for one document instead of an array of such huge size.

Edit: I tried using a list object

```
single_text = ['''Great for the non-audiophile: Reviewed quite a bit of the combo players and was hesitant due to unfavorable reviews and size of machines. I am weaning off my VHS collection, but don't want to replace them with DVD's. This unit is well built, easy to setup and resolution and special effects (no progressive scan for HDTV owners) suitable for many people looking for a versatile product.Cons- No universal remote.''']

def pre_process(single_text,max_len = 100,num_max = 1000):
    tok = Tokenizer(num_words=num_max)
    tok.fit_on_texts(single_text)
    mat_texts = tok.texts_to_matrix(single_text,mode='count')
    cnn_texts_seq = tok.texts_to_sequences(single_text)
    cnn_texts_mat = sequence.pad_sequences(cnn_texts_seq,maxlen=max_len)
    return cnn_texts_mat

print(np.round(loaded_model.predict(pre_process([texts[i]]))))
1
```

This is matching, however there are lot of other values which are not matching with values of original predict function. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `single_text` as a list? You're using a list in the working part. The program will also expect a list in the second: `singe_text=['''lalalalala''']`

Comment: I tried wrapping text within square bracket, and it gave me a single value. However, the value are different from the original predict function for the whole array

Comment: regardless, i will accept this as answer if you post it as it solved my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the working part of the code used a list of texts, all your predictions should also use lists, even if those lists contain only one element. (In keras models, this will represent an input array with the first dimension == 1. The first dimension is the batch size)

So, I suggest you make `single_text` a list:

```
single_text = ['''Great CD: My lovely <removed for visibility> was that singing ?"''']
```

Now, I also think you should not fit the tokenizer again.

It's supposed to recognize all words exactly the same way it did in training. If you fit it again, it will start to produce different tokens and your predictions will naturally be completely different.

You should remove the repeated lines:

```
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=num_max)
tok.fit_on_texts(single_text)
```

And use the original tokenizer (it may be a good idea to save it along with the model, if possible).

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the tokenizer part!!! I just checked and it matched with original result.